# How to project a new field in response in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using **Elasticsearch 6.2**. 
I have an `index` **products** with `index_type` **productA** having data with following structure:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "parts": ["part1", "part2",...] 
  .....
  .....
}
```

Now during the query time, I want to add or project a field `parts_count` to the response which simply represents the number of parts i.e the length of `parts` array. Also, if possible, I would also like to sort the documents of **productA** based on the generated field `parts_count`.

I have gone through most of the docs but haven't found a way to achieve this.

**Note:**
*I don't want to update the mapping and add dynamic fields. I am not sure if Elasticsearch allows it. I just wanted to mention it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read about [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html#search-request-script-fields) and on [Script Based Sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)?

I think you should be able to achieve both things and this not require any mapping updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. One problem I am facing using the `script field` is that I am only getting the `generated field` in response, the original fields are not returned.

Comment: Use `"_source": true` in your request as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36864310/4086321

Comment: Thanks, now I can sort and also return the original fields along with scripted field. However, the scripted fields are returned under `fields` object. Can we also move the scripted fields under `_source` object in the response ?

Comment: I do not think so. The _source field contains the original JSON document body that was passed at index time (see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) and probably cannot be "modified" this way.